# How do I scale an object using raycast in the right direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hi I was trying to make a box on runtime where the initial point is on the first click of the mouse (I have a box with a pivot on the bottom left corner) and then drag to the mouse in the direction where I want to create a box while holding the mouse button (I just scale the box with the distance in x and y).

Like is seeing on the video but for some reason only works on one of the walls, I know that this has to be related with the rotation of the camera, but I don't know if I need to apply some kind of rotation to my scaling object or something else to scale correctly on the four walls.

Note: Here I have only four walls each rotated 90 degrees, but in some cases I can have a wall with other degrees like 45 or 60 to mention some examples.

I attach a video on my error and where only works on the first wall but not correctly on the others, and some snippets of my code.

[Video of the problem](https://youtu.be/qsFOECtMmGA)

```
public GameObject currentBox;
private float speed = 4;

private void Update()
{
    //Rotate with mouse
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        transform.eulerAngles += speed * new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0);
    }
    
    //Box Scale logic
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position); //ray from camera
        
        bool hasHit = Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hitObject, float.PositiveInfinity,
            LayerMask.GetMask("Wall")); //raycast from camera to infinity
        
        //If doesn't hit with wall exit
        if (!hasHit)
            return;

        //If hits
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            //Set the pivot of the box on the first hit point
            currentBox.transform.position = hitObject.point;// + Vector3.back * 0.05f;
            currentBox.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.back, hitObject.normal);
            //Debug.Log("Direction: " + (currentBox.transform.position - transform.position));
        }
        //If mouse is move scale the box with the width and height dimensions
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            float width = hitObject.point.x - currentBox.transform.position.x;
            float height = hitObject.point.y - currentBox.transform.position.y;
            currentBox.transform.localScale = new Vector3(width, height, 0.01f);
            //currentBox.transform.position = hitObject.point;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `TouchPhase.Began`, cache the clicked point and also set a second point equal to that value.

In `TouchPhase.Moved`, update the second point.

After either case, set the rotation equal to hitObject's rotation, position as the average of the two values, and scale as the difference of the two values.

Another issue that you're seeing might be due to you setting the local scale to get your desired width and height, but the actual/effective scale will be determined by that AND the scale of the parent GameObject. I can't see how it's set in the hierarchy, so maybe it's not an issue, but I did notice your planes all are skewed (in scale).

Comment: Let me understand, on touch began I need to save the point two times, first maybe as position of the object and maybe in another variable Vector3, as tempPosition.

Then on the moved, I update the temp position, I calculate the average between the point I have save first and the new point that the mouse is giving me, and then set that as a scale of my object?

Yes I have planes on the four axis and between, just as example here, but some times a wall can be on any angle, 10 degrees or 15 degrees in any direction, but always facing to the camera.

Comment: the parent object of the box I'm creating is 1,1,1 so I think that is not a problem about the scale, and the skewed of the planes is just to show that also that is a some thing that can happen where a plane can have different dimensions, but the parent object of the box and the walls are 0,0,0 on position, 0,0,0 on rotation and 1,1,1 on scale

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but without success

Comment: @Darkmax - the average of the two points gives you the center, which should be the position for the box, and the difference gives you the scale.

Comment: Thanks is working great on the front and back walls works great and on left and right the z value is now x I can handle that with an if but on the 45 degrees walls is os a little difficult because some walls can have that angle or another like 80 or 60 and on those cases the box I’m creating does not cover all the motion I’m doing, how can I handle those intermediary cases?

Comment: @Darkmax Ahh I think maybe I understand what's going on. I'm wondering if you're getting the positions from the clicked points in world coordinates, but you're setting the cube's rotation equal to the plane's rotation. You're trying to treat the world coordinate clicks as local coordinate dimensions and positions. I think you can keep the code for position as-is, but for the scale you would want to convert those points to the plane's local coordinate frame so you get the axes correct. I believe you can do this with `hitObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hitObject.point)`

Comment: You should be able to use the difference between the *transformed* points to calculate scale, and since they've been transformed to the plane's frame the axis swapping should all be handled automatically.